# Диадок сформировать сообщение

Tags: c#, google-protobuf

по http://api-docs.diadoc.ru/ru/latest/howto/example_send_invoice.html

пробую

```
public static GeneratedFile GenerateinvoiceXml(string authToken, string box, string tobox)
{
    try
    {
        var content = new InvoiceInfo()
        {
            // заполняем согласно структуре InvoiceInfo
            InvoiceDate = "31.01.2016",                    // дата СФ
            InvoiceNumber = "11-012016-2410000000",                  // номер СФ
            Seller = {
            BoxId = box
        },
            Buyer = {
            BoxId = tobox
        },
            Signer = {
            SignerCertificate = ReadFileContent(FileWithCertName)
        },

            PaymentDocuments =   {
                new PaymentDocumentInfo
                {
                       DocumentDate = "08.08.2016",
                       DocumentNumber = "№00243015140"
                }
        },
            Items = {
            new InvoiceItem
            {
                Product = "Горячая вода (компонент на тепловую энергию). Прочие",
                CountriesOfOrigin = { "23", "3243" } ,
                TaxRate =  TaxRate.Fraction_10_110,
                Subtotal = "321231"
            }
        },
            AdditionalInfos = {
            new AdditionalInfo
            {
                Id = "2312321",
                Value = "32423423"
            }
        },
            Total = "1000"
        };
        return Api.GenerateInvoiceXml(authToken, content);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        logger.Debug("Except{0}", e, null);
        Console.Read();
        return null;
    }
}
```

получаю

> diadoc_cnsl.Program.GenerateinvoiceXml Debug:
>   ExceptSystem.NullReferenceException: В экземпляре объекта не задана
>   ссылка на объект.    в diadoc_cnsl.Program.GenerateinvoiceXml(String
>   authToken, String box, String tobox)

каким образом правильно сформировать сообщение?

как понимаю используется https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойства не обязаны быть заполнены, создавайте экземпляры классов, не забывайте:

```
      Seller = new DiadocOrganizationInfo()
      {
        BoxId = box
      },
      Buyer = new DiadocOrganizationInfo()
      {
        BoxId = tobox
      },
      Signer = new Signer()
      {
        SignerCertificate = null
      },
```

Ну и сразу, в текущем виде будет ошибка:

> InvoiceInfo.Seller.OrgInfo.Address.RussianAddress.Region is required

Comment: откуда вы узнали?

Comment: а как описывать страну происхождения?       CountriesOfOrigin = { "7" }  , получаю  AdditionalMessage=Could not recognize InvoiceInfo.Items[0].CountriesOfOrigin[0]: 7,

Comment: @des1roer `DiadocOrganizationInfo` проще не строить вручную, а запросить из сервиса. В одном случае - это ваша организация, где то в `GetMyOriganizations`, а во втором - контрагента, посмотрите в `GetBox`.